# Saving a mllib decision tree model to hdfs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a Mllib decision tree model trained on a set of data. I want to be able to save and load the trained model whenever necessary.e.g. assume I train on million row data set and save it for future use. I found that using FileInputStream,FileOutputStream,ObjectInputStream,ObjectOutputStream I can save and load a Linear model because they made those constructor public as below.

you can save model to disk as following:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream 
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream 
val fos = new FileOutputStream("e:/model.obj") 
val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)   
oos.writeObject(model)   
oos.close
```

and load it in:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream 
import java.io.ObjectInputStream 
val fos = new FileInputStream("e:/model.obj") 
val oos = new ObjectInputStream(fos) 
val newModel = oos.readObject().asInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel]
```

The above does syntactically works for DecisionTree as well but I cannot call the newModel.predict() since the Decision Tree constructors were not made public apparently.

Does anyone now how I can save and load models like DecisionTree,RandomForest,SVM,etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `.save` method on the model to store it as parquet file and load it via `.load` on the companion object. That saves it as parquet file, this should be faster than using plain java serialization, which is often slow.

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.util.Saveable